# Stationary processes

Tags: stationary-processes

I'm still learning English so I'm already sorry for what's going to happen.
I don't know if I am right about the strictly stationary.
Let's suppose a process is strictly stationary: does that mean $X_t$ and $X_{t+h}$ (for all $h>0$) have the same distribution  of probability ?

Thank you

Comment: And also for all t which is defined Z.